# how to override the JQuery ajax call function?

Tags: jquery, overriding

I have a JavaScript function with 4 parameter

```
function GetEmpDetails(EmpID, ApplicationID, ActionID, ApplicationSubID) 
{  
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/TransController/GetEmpInformation',
    data: { "EmpID": JSON.stringify(EmpID), "ApplicationID": ApplicationID, "ActionID": ActionID, "ApplicationSubID": ApplicationSubID },
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    success: function (data) {
        DisplayDetails(data);
    },
    error: function (result) {
    }
  });
}
```

I want to override the same function with one different parameter. something as below

```
function GetEmpDetails(EmpID, ApplicationID, ActionID, DateOfJoining) 
{  
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/TransController/GetEmpInformation',
    data: { "EmpID": JSON.stringify(EmpID), "ApplicationID": ApplicationID, "ActionID": ActionID, "DateOfJoining": DateOfJoining},
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    success: function (data) {
        DisplayDetails(data);
    },
    error: function (result) {
    }
  });
}
```

Someone please tell, Is it possible to do and how with some example code?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data as object

```
function GetEmpDetails(data) 
{  
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/TransController/GetEmpInformation',
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    success: function (data) {
        DisplayDetails(data);
    },
    error: function (result) {
    }
  });
}
```

Usage

```
GetEmpDetails({EmpID: "", ...,  ApplicationSubID: ""})
GetEmpDetails({EmpID: "", ...,  Whatever: ""})
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using additional parameters (very similar to python's `**kwargs`?

```
function GetEmpDetails(EmpID, ApplicationID, ActionID, AdditionalParameters) 
{  
  var data = AdditionalParameters;
  $.extend(data, { "EmpID": JSON.stringify(EmpID), "ApplicationID": ApplicationID, "ActionID": ActionID})
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/TransController/GetEmpInformation',
    data: data, 
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    success: function (data) {
        DisplayDetails(data);
    },
    error: function (result) {
    }
  });
}
```

Now call your function in one of these two ways:

```
GetEmpDetails(1, 1, 1, {"DateOfJoining": DateOfJoining});
GetEmpDetails(1, 1, 1, {"ApplicationSubID": 1});
```